# Why python3 manage.py runserver built-in command also runs my custom commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

app_name is added INSTALLED_APPS = [] and
in my path /app_name/management/commands/custom.py

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import server


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        server.start()
```

i runned python3 manage.py custom.py

it runned the code in my server file fine
but now when i run : python3 manage.py runserver  on the console activity i can see that python3 manage.py custom.py is automatically called within runserver command

How can i Stop this from Happening?

Comment: How did you verify that the `custom.py` module is called?

Comment: i should and will update my post  . i assumed  it was called automatically  because the code from ```server.start()``` is printed. but now i dont know because i tried removing app_name from INSTALLED_APPS = [], and even deleting that app but the code from  ```server.start()``` is still printing whenever i call any built-in commands i usually call (migrate, makemigration... etc).

Comment: Perhaps there is another `server.start()` call in your project. Perhaps do a recursive search through your project for that.

Comment: i just did the check there is no other ```server.start()``` in my project i commented out the "custom.py" and the problem persist it might be cache or my project is haunted

Comment: Any `__pycache__` directories hanging around?

Comment: It might also be your IDE/editor messing with things: some seem to be a bit overzealous.

Comment: By the way, the command should simply be `python3 manage.py custom.py`. No `.py` extension needed. That actually shouldn't even work.

Comment: yeah writing mistake i didnt include .py